# Need help to create objects inside array

Tags: bash, loops, jq

jq query as like this ,

```sh
jq -n  --arg cname "$1" --arg dns "$2" '
  {
    "extra_vars": {
      "oper_tasks": [ "records" ],
      "zone_info": [
        {
          "zone": "exmple.com",
          "records": [
            {
              "name": $cname,
              "type": "CNAME",
              "value": $dns,
              "ttl": 3600
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
'
```

The above jq cn produce something like this , cname and dns can be filled with arguments when we execute as script.

```json
"extra_vars": {
    "oper_tasks": [
      "records"
    ],
    "zone_info": [
      {
        "zone": "exmple.com",
        "records": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "CNAME",
            "value": "",
            "ttl": 3600
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how we can create more than one objects like below from an input file.  something like how we do in for loop.

```
"extra_vars": {
"oper_tasks": [
  "records"
],
"zone_info": [
  {
    "zone": "exmple.com",
    "records": [
      {
        "name": <cname1 from input file>,
        "type": "CNAME",
        "value": "",
        "ttl": 3600
      },
      {
        "name": <cname2 from input file>,
        "type": "CNAME",
        "value": "",
        "ttl": 3600
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

Comment: What should tjhe value of `name` be ? How much objects etc? Please include more details about the desired outcome.

Comment: A simplified view of the problem: `null | .names`. This can't possibly work. And it's not clear what you want that to do. Should `.names[($name)]` be replaced with `$name`?

Comment: @vikree - Welcome to SO!  Please review the [mcve] guidelines, and clarify your question accordingly.  It would probably be best to focus on one particular question, with a clear example that shows the input(s) and corresponding expected result.

Comment: hello All.. sorry for lack of clarity... now updated with relevant information. please help to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that you have a file `cnames.txt` where each line contains one CNAME domain followed by its value:

```
foo.example.com google.com
bar.example.com stackoverflow.com
```

Let us create that file:

```sh
cat <<EOF > cnames.txt
foo.example.com google.com
bar.example.com stackoverflow.com
EOF
```

You can "nest" one `jq` into the other by using `--slurpfile` described in the [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). The following command should do what you want:

```sh
cat cnames.txt | xargs -n2 jq -n '{
    "name": $ARGS.positional[0],
    "type": "CNAME",
    "value": $ARGS.positional[1],
    "ttl": 3600
}' --args | jq -n --slurpfile records /dev/stdin '
  {
    "extra_vars": {
      "oper_tasks": [ "records" ],
      "zone_info": [
        {
          "zone": "example.com",
          "records": $records
        }
      ]
    }
  }
'
```

which returns:

```json
{
  "extra_vars": {
    "oper_tasks": [
      "records"
    ],
    "zone_info": [
      {
        "zone": "example.com",
        "records": [
          {
            "name": "foo.example.com",
            "type": "CNAME",
            "value": "google.com",
            "ttl": 3600
          },
          {
            "name": "bar.example.com",
            "type": "CNAME",
            "value": "stackoverflow.com",
            "ttl": 3600
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```